# Program variable name to Google chart

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have a chart in Google spreadsheets. The content changes when selecting a menu, with drop down menu. Everything works, except I can't get the chart name to be flexible too.

I want the chart name to be cell A1.

What is wrong with my code?

```
}

function expandCharts() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
// Get a list of all charts on this Sheet.
var charts = sheet.getCharts();
 for (var i in charts) {
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D4"); 
 var chart = charts[i];
 var cell = range.getCell(1,1);
                 var ranges = chart.getRanges();
// Returns an EmbeddedChartBuilder with this chart’s settings.
var builder = chart.modify();
for (var j in ranges) {
  var range = ranges[j];

}
// Update title.
builder.setOption('title', 'Netliq ' + cell)
// Must be called to save changes.
sheet.updateChart(builder.build());
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **.getValue()** in order to set **cell** equal to the contents of **A1**'s.

Try this:

```
var cell = range.getCell(1,1).getValue();
```